# What's the best way to copy an array and keep the keys with empty values

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, what's the best way to copy an array and keep the keys with empty values?

```
array1 = array("apple" => "green", "banana" => "yellow);
```

I want to copy array1 to array2 and keep only the keys...

```
array2 = array("apple" => "", "banana" => "");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return array_fill_keys(array_keys($array1), "");
```

(Example run: http://www.ideone.com/SuMt2)

Answer (score 2):

What about [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), it return an array that has the keys of another array as values.

You can then use [array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to change keys for values and voilá, you have your result.

In a nutshell:

```
$array2 = array_flip(array_keys($array1));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `foreach` to produce a new array, or one of numerous [array functions](http://php.net/ref.array)